# Hibernate Annotation (Pyramid Structure - same table)

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have a person table that contains the following fields:

id, name, parent_id.

the parent_id is actually a FK for column id.
the data should look like this (Like a pyramid):

```
"id"   "name"                  "parent_id"

"1"    "I am the Top Father"   "1"
"2"    "My Father Is 1"        "1"
"3"    "My Father Is 2"        "2"
"4"    "My Father Is 2"        "2"
```

How is my bean suppose to look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="persons")
public class Person {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Person parent;

    ...

}
```

Have a look at the [Hibernate Annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/) reference.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. how do you annotate this? what is Foo and how is that connected to id?

Comment: Foo is your pojo. I'll rename it to Person.

Comment: How come, i can add to parent_id values that are not existed? meaning parent Id allowing none existed parents. thanks

Comment: If a person doesn't have a parent then it's preferable to have a null `parent_id` than a dummy (non existent) value.